# Sublime Text 2: How to set up consistent syntax highlighting for Guardfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, sublimetext2, guard

While it is easy enough to set the language for a given (open) file in Sublime Text, I'm wondering if there is any way that I can tell the editor in advance that anything called "Guardfile" should be highlighted like it's Ruby code. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I happened to come across this plugin that will likely help you: https://github.com/phillipkoebbe/DetectSyntax

Comment: Or, to simplify & address the core issue: http://brizzled.clapper.org/blog/2012/02/06/a-sublime-text-2-plugin-to-set-the-syntax-from-the-file-name/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The plugins recommended in the comments by Brian both do the job nicely:

1. [ApplySyntax](https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax)
2. [SyntaxFromFileName](http://brizzled.clapper.org/blog/2012/02/06/%E2%80%A6)

**Update:**

I couldn't get SyntaxFromFileName to match any of my regex for some reason. On the other hand, **DetectSyntax comes with syntax highlight for the Guardfile *built in***.

**Update2:**

DetectSyntax has been [renamed](https://github.com/phillipkoebbe/DetectSyntax) to ApplySyntax

Comment: My theory is that `SyntaxFromFileName` doesn't work with a `Guardfile` because a Guardfile doesn't have an extension. Anyway, just confirming `ApplySyntax` highlights wonderfully with ambiguous files.

Answer (score 7):

Putting the following at the top of said file also works

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```